# Utilizar variables para indices de una lista en una clase

Tags: python, lista, class

Estoy tratando de generar un reporte que me muestre los valores de una lista. Al tener un solo elemento en la lista todo trabaja perfecto y obtengo los datos que necesito, el tema es que al tratar de obtener el resto de los elementos, no logro decifrar como hacerlo ya que los valores de la clase los estoy estableciendo con el indice de la lista y al "presentarlos" solo me muestra los del primer indice.

Lo que quiero preguntar es si hay alguna manera de convertir ese indice en un rango o algo asi.

Este es el codigo:

```
prueba = '''
{
    "result": [
        {
            "category": "Personal",
            "confidence": "",
            "country": "unknown",
            "device": "compu",
            "dhcp_fingerprint": "",
            "event_time": "2021-03-25T17:48:09.000Z",
            "feed_name": "Personal",
            "feed_type": "FQDN",
            "mac_address": "d4:6d:6d:08:xx:xx",
            "network": "CASA",
            "os_version": "Windows",
            "policy_name": "politica",
            "private_ip": "10.0.0.12",
            "qip": "189.217.xxx.xxx",
            "qname": "dl-debug.dropbox.com.",
            "qtype": "A",
            "rcode": "REDIRECT",
            "rdata": "52.4.xxx.xxx",
            "rip": "",
            "severity": "",
            "tclass": "",
            "threat_indicator": "CAT",
            "tproperty": "",
            "user": "user"
        },
        {
            "category": "Streaming",
            "confidence": "",
            "country": "unknown",
            "device": "compu",
            "dhcp_fingerprint": "",
            "event_time": "2021-03-25T17:43:32.000Z",
            "feed_name": "Streaming",
            "feed_type": "FQDN",
            "mac_address": "d4:6d:6d:08:xx:xx",
            "network": "Casa",
            "os_version": "Windows",
            "policy_name": "politica",
            "private_ip": "10.0.0.12",
            "qip": "189.217.xxx.xxx",
            "qname": "cs9.wac.phicdn.net.",
            "qtype": "AAAA",
            "rcode": "PASSTHRU",
            "rdata": "",
            "rip": "",
            "severity": "",
            "tclass": "",
            "threat_indicator": "CAT",
            "tproperty": "",
            "user": "user"
        },
        {
            "category": "Games",
            "confidence": "",
            "country": "US",
            "device": "compu",
            "dhcp_fingerprint": "",
            "event_time": "2021-03-25T17:43:18.000Z",
            "feed_name": "Games",
            "feed_type": "FQDN",
            "mac_address": "d4:6d:6d:08:xx:xx",
            "network": "Casa",
            "os_version": "Windows",
            "policy_name": "politica",
            "private_ip": "10.0.0.12",
            "qip": "189.217.xxx.xxx",
            "qname": "cdn-icon.bluestacks.com.",
            "qtype": "A",
            "rcode": "PASSTHRU",
            "rdata": "99.84.xxx.xxx",
            "rip": "",
            "severity": "",
            "tclass": "",
            "threat_indicator": "CAT",
            "tproperty": "",
            "user": "user"
        }],
    "status_code": "200"}'''

class dns_report:
    def __init__(self, result, status_code):
        self.result = result
        self.index = len(result)
        self.category = result[0]['category']
        self.device = result[0]['device']
        self.event_time = result[0]['event_time']
        self.os_version = result[0]['os_version']
        self.policy_name = result[0]['policy_name']
        self.rcode = result[0]['rcode']
        self.user = result[0]['user']
        
    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls,prueba):
        json_dict = json.loads(prueba)
        return cls(**json_dict)
            
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Categoria = { self.category }, Device = { self.device }, Event Time = { self.event_time }\
        OS Version = { self.os_version }, Policy Name = { self.policy_name }, Action = { self.rcode },User = { self.user }'
    
report = dns_report.from_json(prueba)
print(report)
```

Si cambio el indice de "0" a "1" obtengo el siguiente resultado, pero no es opcion hacerlo manual.

Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder iterar en arrays puedes utilizar un `for... in`, en el cual accedes a cada elemento del array utilizando un "alias", esto es sumamente útil al trabajar con los diccionarios que están dentro de tu array porque puedes hacer referencia a las propiedades internas del mismo.

Mira este ejemplo en el cuál obtenemos acceso al usuario y la categoría de cada elemento dentro del array.

```
import json

prueba = '''
{
    "result": [
        {
            "category": "Personal",
            "confidence": "",
            "country": "unknown",
            "device": "compu",
            "dhcp_fingerprint": "",
            "event_time": "2021-03-25T17:48:09.000Z",
            "feed_name": "Personal",
            "feed_type": "FQDN",
            "mac_address": "d4:6d:6d:08:xx:xx",
            "network": "CASA",
            "os_version": "Windows",
            "policy_name": "politica",
            "private_ip": "10.0.0.12",
            "qip": "189.217.xxx.xxx",
            "qname": "dl-debug.dropbox.com.",
            "qtype": "A",
            "rcode": "REDIRECT",
            "rdata": "52.4.xxx.xxx",
            "rip": "",
            "severity": "",
            "tclass": "",
            "threat_indicator": "CAT",
            "tproperty": "",
            "user": "user"
        },
        {
            "category": "Streaming",
            "confidence": "",
            "country": "unknown",
            "device": "compu",
            "dhcp_fingerprint": "",
            "event_time": "2021-03-25T17:43:32.000Z",
            "feed_name": "Streaming",
            "feed_type": "FQDN",
            "mac_address": "d4:6d:6d:08:xx:xx",
            "network": "Casa",
            "os_version": "Windows",
            "policy_name": "politica",
            "private_ip": "10.0.0.12",
            "qip": "189.217.xxx.xxx",
            "qname": "cs9.wac.phicdn.net.",
            "qtype": "AAAA",
            "rcode": "PASSTHRU",
            "rdata": "",
            "rip": "",
            "severity": "",
            "tclass": "",
            "threat_indicator": "CAT",
            "tproperty": "",
            "user": "user"
        },
        {
            "category": "Games",
            "confidence": "",
            "country": "US",
            "device": "compu",
            "dhcp_fingerprint": "",
            "event_time": "2021-03-25T17:43:18.000Z",
            "feed_name": "Games",
            "feed_type": "FQDN",
            "mac_address": "d4:6d:6d:08:xx:xx",
            "network": "Casa",
            "os_version": "Windows",
            "policy_name": "politica",
            "private_ip": "10.0.0.12",
            "qip": "189.217.xxx.xxx",
            "qname": "cdn-icon.bluestacks.com.",
            "qtype": "A",
            "rcode": "PASSTHRU",
            "rdata": "99.84.xxx.xxx",
            "rip": "",
            "severity": "",
            "tclass": "",
            "threat_indicator": "CAT",
            "tproperty": "",
            "user": "user"
        }],
    "status_code": "200"}'''

json_dict = json.loads(prueba)

for resultado in json_dict["result"]:
    print(f'Categoria: {resultado["category"]}, usuario: {resultado["user"]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Además de la respuesta anterior, también podrías añadir un método en la clase como el siguiente:

```
def print_report(self):
        for x in self.result:
            print(f"Categoria = { x['category'] }, Device = { x['device'] }, Event Time = { x['event_time'] }\
        OS Version = { x['os_version'] }, Policy Name = { x['policy_name'] }, Action = { x['rcode'] },User = { x['user'] }")
```

Recorres cada uno de los datos que almacenaste en el atributo `result` de la clase que son c/u de los elementos (`self.result`) y los imprimes.

Llamas al método de la siguiente manera:

```
report.print_report()
```